# large number of linear equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I want to use `solve()` to solve a large system of linear equations. The `solve()` function needs equations and variables. I use a loop to generate the equations and my variables are contained in a large array. This is a simple code of what I am trying to do:

```
x = sym('x',[1 3])
eqn = sym('eqn', [1,3])
eqn1 = 2*x1 + x2 + x3 - 2 == 0
eqn2 = 2*x2 -x2 -x1- x3 == 3
eqn3 = 2*x2+ x1 + 3*x3 == -10
Y = solve(eqn, x)
```

MATLAB does not recognize my variable `x1`. I have solved the same system using the following code:

```
syms x1 x2 x3
eqn1 = 2*x1 + x2 + x3 == 2
eqn2 =   2*x2 -x2 -x1 - x3 == 3
eqn3 = 2*x2+ x1 + 3*x3 == -10
X = solve([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4], [x1 x2 x3])
structfun(@subs,X)
```

But this is useless for a very large number of equations. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need symbolic (`syms`) for that. This is a standard linear system of equations that can be represented as:
`Ax = b` where `A = [2 1 1; -1 1 -1; 1 2 3]`, `x = [x1; x2; x3]` and `b = [0; 3; -10]`

To solve for x, you would first define

`A = [2 1 1; -1 1 -1; 1 2 3]`

and

`b = [0; 3; -10]`

and then solve using

`x = A\b`

PS. There are some odd things in your question, eg. in eq.2 `eqn2 = 2*x2 -x2 -x1- x3 == 3` I assume you omitted simplying this to `-x1 +x2 -x3 ==3`.

PS2. This is pretty standard Matlab, you can find a lot of info under the standard [mldivide page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) in the documentation along with a lot similar questions here on SO.